# Rails mountable engine: how to bundle in each app that uses it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, rails-engines

I have a private rails mountable engine (in a private repo) that several of my projects use.

It is included with a local path in their Gemfile.

**Is there a way to package the engine during deployment into each app's repo?** (maybe via /vendor/cache or something).

i.e. So I wouldn't need to do these two steps which I currently have to do:

- Have the engine in it's own folder on the server that the apps have to reference (with that relative path).
- After updating the engine, I can chose which app gets the latest updates of the engine. (Right now when I commit engine updates in the repo and update it on the production server, all apps using get the updates).

From the [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html), I could add the engine gem as `gem 'blorgh', path: "vendor/engines/blorgh"` But how do I keep the engine code in a central place and cherry pick which app gets the update?

Answer (score 1):

I would make a private repo on Github, and reference it by `:git` in each app's `Gemfile` and use `:tag`, `:branch`, or `:ref` to do you cherry-pick work.

```
# in app1 Gemfile.rb
gem 'blorgh', :git => 'git@github.com:jacob/blorgh', :tag => 'v1.1'

# in app2 Gemfile.rb
gem 'blorgh', :git => 'git@github.com:jacob/blorgh', :ref => '4aded'
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: But then wouldn't the repo need to be public?